# Wordpress site on AWS throws 404 error on all but homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, amazon-web-services

I have a site that is live on AWS - Wordpress, latest version, custom theme

It works fine in MAMP on my laptop, but on the live site, none of the pages besides the homepage work with the permalinks as /%post-name%/

I can make the permalinks work if I change them to default.

I don't *think* it has to do with htaccess, I've tried scrubbing it, we made some edits to it, and that has not made a difference.

Here are the contents of htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ucampaign/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ucampaign/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I *think* it has to do with settings in the AWS instance, which I know can get complicated.  But I wouldn't know where to look.

Thank you for looking at this, if there's more information needed to figure this out, I will be happy to provide  :-)

Comment: have you installed/enabled mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a missing mod_rewrite. check apache config for that. Also, make sure Apache is reading the .htaccess file. When I say check to make sure the .htaccess is being read, does the server throw an error when you place junk inside the .htaccess file? What type of OS are you running on AWS?

Comment: hey thanks, i'm trying to get SSH access to give these suggestions a shot.  it won't let me up vote anything though bc i'm a n0000000b :(

Comment: will follow up with results